# Run method after deploying and save the result with to database

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, quarkus

I have started a Quarkus project and i have there 2 tables, i am trying to run a Method immediately after deploying, In the method i use Entitymanger to save some results in the database.

In pure Jakarta EE, you could an EJB and annotate it with @Startup. But Since quarkus uses CDI.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StartApp {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Employee";
    public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object init) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        Directory directory = new Directory("/some/info", true, false, ".xml");
        em.persist(directory);
        em.close();
    }
}
```

How can i do that!? some guess !

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class StartApp {
    void startup(@Observes StartupEvent event) { 
       // Do whatever needs to be done.
    }
}
```

More information and options can be found on the very well documented quarkus pages. https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#startup-event

Ps. don't forget about your transactions and maybe take a look at Hibernate ORM.